# Flatten a named list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
things <- list(
    "thing1" = "foo",
    "thing2" = "bar",
    "thing4" = c("baz", "qux"),
    "thing5" = c("quux", "quuz", "corge"),
    "thing6" = "grault"
)
```

I'd like a solution that turns the irregular list into a character matrix like this:

```
+----------+----------+
| "thing1" | "foo"    |
| "thing2" | "bar"    |
| "thing4" | "baz"    |
| "thing4" | "qux"    |
| "thing5" | "quux"   |
| "thing5" | "quuz"   |
| "thing5" | "corge"  |
| "thing6" | "grault" |
+----------+----------+
```

The real example is too long to do by hand.

Comment: Don't use `<-` inside `list`, use `=` instead. You also need commas. Please check the code that you provide.

Comment: `data.frame(names = rep(names(things), lengths(things)), things = unlist(things), row.names = NULL)`

Comment: A tidyverse version: `library(tidyverse); things %>% map(list) %>% as_data_frame() %>% gather() %>% unnest()` or with the dev version of purrr, `things %>% imap_dfr(~data_frame(id = .y, value = .x))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
as.matrix(stack(things))[, c(2, 1)]

#     ind      values  
# [1,] "thing1" "foo"   
# [2,] "thing2" "bar"   
# [3,] "thing4" "baz"   
# [4,] "thing4" "qux"   
# [5,] "thing5" "quux"  
# [6,] "thing5" "quuz"  
# [7,] "thing5" "corge" 
# [8,] "thing6" "grault"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility (in base R):

```
cbind(rep(names(things), times = lengths(things)), unname(unlist(things)))

#     [,1]     [,2]    
#[1,] "thing1" "foo"   
#[2,] "thing2" "bar"   
#[3,] "thing4" "baz"   
#[4,] "thing4" "qux"   
#[5,] "thing5" "quux"  
#[6,] "thing5" "quuz"  
#[7,] "thing5" "corge" 
#[8,] "thing6" "grault"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `melt`

```
library(reshaep2)
as.matrix(melt(things)[2:1])
```